# How can I add a character to a random space of a string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string: `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.` I want to insert a `,` (comma and space) into a random spot where there currently is just a  (space). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```js
var string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.',
    array = string.split(' '),
    i = Math.random() * (array.length - 1) | 0;

array[i] += ',';
string = array.join(' ');
document.write(string);
```